# Concatenate lists based on a shared value

Tags: python, list

I have the following two lists, `l1` and `l2`.

```py
l1 = [('8012387', {'key': values}), ('10556298', {'key': values}), ...]
l2 = [('8012387', 'TextA'), ('10556298', 'TextB'), ...]
```

I want to combine the two lists such that I will have the following.

```py
[('TextA', {'key': values}), ('textB', {'key': values}), ...]
```

I did not know how to start.

Comment: are they both same length and order? If so I would start with getting range on them and then do list comprehension with tuple creation (l2[i][1], l1[i][1])

Comment: Are the lists in the same order, or do you have to find the common values?

Comment: If you have to find the matching values, use nested loops or convert one of the lists into a dictionary.

Comment: Both lists are of the same length and order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `l2` into a dict to lookup the keys and then build the list you want with a list comprehension:

```
l1 = [('8012387', {'key': 'values'}), ('10556298', {'key': 'values2'})]
l2 = [('8012387', 'TextA'), ('10556298', 'TextB')]

d_l2 = dict(l2)

[(d_l2[k], obj) for k, obj in l1]
# [('TextA', {'key': 'values'}), ('TextB', {'key': 'values2'})]
```

This assumes all the keys are present in `l2`. If not you'll have to define the behavior you want in that case.

If the lists are aligned (i.e. `l2[0`] correpsonds to `l1[0]`, etc). You can just zip them:

```
[(k, v) for (_1, v), (_2, k) in  zip(l1, l2)]
```